# How do you find new speed of a object knowing the momentum and impulse?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I know that both momentum and impulse (change in momentum) are measured in kg m/s and the formula for momentum is mass x velocity and the formula for impulse is force x time. However I have a question regarding both of them in one question.

The question is this:

A force of 8.6N acted for 2.5s on an object of mass 1.8kg initially moving at 50m/s. Calculate the objects new speed.

Is there a formula for this type of question?

Also here is what I have worked out so far.

Impulse = 8.6N x 2.5s = 21.5 Ns or kgm/s
Initial momentum = 1.8 x 50 = 90 kgm/s

I am not sure where to go from here. Do I add the impulse and initial momentum (111.5) and divide by the mass to find the new speed? Is that how it works?

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Impulse = Change in momentum ,

hence : $F \cdot t = m \cdot \Delta v$

where $\Delta v = v_2-v_1$

And therefore $F \cdot t = m \cdot (v_2-v_1) $

So You have one equation with one unknown $(v_2)$ .

Can You proceed from here ?

Answer (score 0):

When force is integrated,

$$ F \Delta t = m \Delta v,$$

$$ 8.6  \cdot 2.5 = 1.8 ( v_{new}-50).  $$

from which $v_{new} $ can be found. It is assumed the mass of the object (unlike a rocket burning fuel) does not change.